# C# Razor Pages and Cross Site Scripting(XSS) problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xss, razor-pages

I have an AspNet Core Razor Pages application, for security reasons, and to avoid Cross Site Scripting (XSS) I used the Nwebsec library which allows me to add a middleware like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Other config

    app.UseXXssProtection(options => options.EnabledWithBlockMode());
    app.UseCsp(options =>
    {
        options.ScriptSources(conf => conf.Self())
            .ScriptSources(conf => conf.CustomSources("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js", 
                    "https://......"));
     });
     ......
}
```

in order to avoid the injection of scripts in the url of some pages.
Everything works correctly, but the problem is that the application must open an external authentication provider (eg saml request on ADFS) and the opening of the page is blocked due to the presence of inline js script (from the external provider). If I try to put:

```
app.UseCsp(options =>
    {
        options.ScriptSources(conf => conf.Self())
            .ScriptSources(conf => conf.CustomSources("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js", 
                    "https://......").UnsafeInline()); // Unsafe inline script
     });
```

all inline scripts are accepted and thus the application becomes vulnerable. Does anyone know how I can fix it? Are there other libraries to achieve my goal?
Thanks so much

Comment: it's a bit strange for the external authentication provider to require (or generate) an URL that contains inline js script. Could you share a sample format of such URL? the external authentication provider may have its option to use another format.

Comment: No, the problem is not that the URL contains a script, the problem is that when the app tries to open the page of the external provider, it does not open, and in the browser, I see that it has been blocked due to an inline script in the page

Comment: As I wrote if I add the call to UnsafeInline () the ADFS page is opened quietly, otherwise, it is blocked

Comment: by this `in order to avoid the injection of scripts in the url of some pages` - I understand that it just tries to process the request (the url) and blocks it if something goes wrong. So basically it should not even touch the loaded content (from the url). Otherwise that's an error in the middleware you use.

Comment: if possible, please make this `the application must open an external authentication provider` clear, how it opens ...? that's the point where the issue starts. I really don't get that as well because the middleware you use just processes the incoming requests (to your server) not some kind of outgoing requests (to another server).

Comment: It is authentication with SAML2 protocol that takes place through an HTTP Redirect